# Sublime Text, move tabs with keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In Sublime Text 3, is there a way to reorganize tabs using keyboard only?

I know you can switch a tab from a pane to another pane using for example `ctrl+shift+2` to move a tab from pane X to pane 2 but it's not exactly what I am looking for.

I am looking to move a tab in its pane. For example, I have 3 tabs and I want to interchange tab 1 and 2. It's doable using the mouse but I have not found any keyboard shortcut for it.

Tabs in their original position

### [image: Tabs in position 1]

Tab 1 has been moved one the right

[image: Tabs in position 2]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Nope. However, the following plugin will give you that functionality.

https://github.com/SublimeText/MoveTab

You can install it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Command palette), type/select `Package Control: Install Package`, then `MoveTab`.

Then you can immediately move tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

Comment: and for mac users the hot keys are `cmd+opt+shift+left` and `cmd+opt+shift+right`

Comment: Also this plugin provides Move Tab: To first position & Move Tab: To last position commands in the command palette, which is very useful if you have a large number of tabs open and want to quickly move a tab to the first or last position.

Comment: Nice! Now my Sublime Text acts the same way as Firefox and Gnome Terminal =)

Comment: For anyone else who wanted to modify the keybindings for MoveTab - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532584/2033526

Comment: I was hoping to move tabs between panes in the split-pane view. That is not what MoveTab does just in case that saves anyone 60 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

On a related note: while this is not the answer to your exact question, many people landing on this page (myself included) may be looking for **how to *switch tabs* with the keyboard**.

Here's how to do that:

- Tab navigation:

  - Cycle through open tabs in the order they were opened = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> / in opposite order they were opened = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
  - Cycle through tabs to the Left / Right = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Source where I learned some of that: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/switching-tabs-with-keyboard/427

Comment: You will find this is a common macro among tabbed programs such as text editors and browsers